# how to add black borders to filled points in ggplot scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this:

```
# Install and load the ggplot2 package
if (!requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
library(ggplot2)

# Set a random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate more random data with overlapping points
num_points <- 40000
data <- data.frame(
  hours_studied = runif(num_points, min = 0, max = 10),
  exam_scores = rnorm(num_points, mean = 50, sd = 15),
  gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = num_points, replace = TRUE)
)

# Create a scatterplot using ggplot2
ggplot(data, aes(x = hours_studied, y = exam_scores, color=gender)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "Dense Scatterplot with More Overlapping Points",
    x = "Hours Studied",
    y = "Exam Scores"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I want to add a black border around each point.

I tried this:

```
# Install and load the ggplot2 package
if (!requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
library(ggplot2)

# Set a random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate more random data with overlapping points
num_points <- 100000
data <- data.frame(
  hours_studied = runif(num_points, min = 0, max = 10),
  exam_scores = rnorm(num_points, mean = 50, sd = 15),
  gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = num_points, replace = TRUE)
)

# Create a scatterplot using ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = hours_studied, y = exam_scores))
p <-  p  + geom_point(data=data, size = 2, alpha=.5, color = "black", stroke = 0.75)
p <- p  + geom_point(data=data, size=1.5, alpha=.5, aes(color=gender))
```

but it plots the black first then the colored points, so if you have a lot of points in one area it looks strange (especially if they are all the same color in that region)

[image]

I think I am looking for something that is more akin to this, but colored by gender:

```
# Install and load the ggplot2 package
if (!requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
library(ggplot2)

# Set a random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate more random data with overlapping points
num_points <- 100000
data <- data.frame(
  hours_studied = runif(num_points, min = 0, max = 10),
  exam_scores = rnorm(num_points, mean = 50, sd = 15),
  gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = num_points, replace = TRUE)
)

# Create a scatterplot using ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = hours_studied, y = exam_scores))
p <- p+ geom_point(fill='blue', color='black', pch=21)
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you want `geom_point(aes(fill = gender), shape = 21, color = "black")`